# Enabling point in time restore for storage account fails with FeatureNotSupportedForAccount

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I am trying to create a new storage account with point in time restore. I've enabled all the prerequisites (soft delete, change feed & versioning). Once I try to deploy the resource, the deployment of the storage account succeeds, but the deployment of the default blob service fails with the following error:

```json
{
    "code": "DeploymentFailed",
    "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
    "details": [
        {
            "code": "FeatureNotSupportedForAccount",
            "message": "Point-In-Time Restore is not supported for the account."
        }
    ]
}
```

In the storage account I've created, point in time restore is disabled once it is deployed. This is what my properties look like:

```json
    "parameters": {
      "location": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "germanywestcentral"
      },
      "storageAccountName": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "REDACTED"
      },
      "accountType": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "StorageV2"
      },
      "accessTier": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "Hot"
      },
      "minimumTlsVersion": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "TLS1_2"
      },
      "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "publicNetworkAccess": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "Enabled"
      },
      "allowBlobPublicAccess": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": false
      },
      "allowSharedKeyAccess": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": false
      },
      "allowCrossTenantReplication": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": false
      },
      "defaultOAuth": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "allowedCopyScope": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "PrivateLink"
      },
      "networkAclsBypass": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "AzureServices"
      },
      "networkAclsDefaultAction": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "Allow"
      },
      "dnsEndpointType": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "Standard"
      },
      "isVersionLevelWormEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "keySource": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "Microsoft.Storage"
      },
      "encryptionEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "keyTypeForTableAndQueueEncryption": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "Account"
      },
      "infrastructureEncryptionEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "isContainerRestoreEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "containerRestorePeriodDays": {
        "type": "Int",
        "value": 14
      },
      "isBlobSoftDeleteEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "blobSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
        "type": "Int",
        "value": 15
      },
      "isContainerSoftDeleteEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "containerSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
        "type": "Int",
        "value": 15
      },
      "changeFeed": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "isVersioningEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "isShareSoftDeleteEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "shareSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
        "type": "Int",
        "value": 15
      }
```

I've tried to enable point in time restore for the storage account that was created, but I receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Point-in-time restore supports  general-purpose v2 storage accounts in the standard performance tier only.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "germanywestcentral"
        },
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "reprostacc"
        },
        "accountType": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "kind": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "StorageV2"
        },
        "accessTier": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "Hot"
        },
        "publicNetworkAccess": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "Enabled"
        },
        "allowBlobPublicAccess": {
            "type": "Bool",
            "defaultValue": false
        },
        "allowSharedKeyAccess": {
            "type": "Bool",
            "defaultValue": false
        },
      "isContainerRestoreEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "containerRestorePeriodDays": {
        "type": "Int",
        "value": 7
      },
      "isBlobSoftDeleteEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "blobSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
        "type": "Int",
        "value": 15
      },
      "isContainerSoftDeleteEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "containerSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
        "type": "Int",
        "value": 15
      },
      "changeFeed": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "isVersioningEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "isShareSoftDeleteEnabled": {
        "type": "Bool",
        "value": true
      },
      "shareSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
        "type": "Int",
        "value": 15
      },
        "restorePolicy": {
            "type": "Object",
            "defaultValue": {
                "enabled": true,
                "days": 7
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('accountType')]"
            },
            "kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
            "properties": {
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": "[parameters('supportsHttpsTrafficOnly')]",
                "minimumTlsVersion": "[parameters('minimumTlsVersion')]",
                "accessTier": "[parameters('accessTier')]",
                "restorePolicy": "[parameters('restorePolicy')]",
                "networkAcls": {
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "defaultAction": "Allow",
                    "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                    "ipRules": []
                },
                "encryption": {
                    "services": {
                        "file": {
                            "enabled": true
                        },
                        "blob": {
                            "enabled": true
                        }
                    },
                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage",
                    "keyVaultProperties": {}
                },
                "publicNetworkAccess": "[parameters('publicNetworkAccess')]"
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I got validation failed:

[image]

**Note:**

> Hot and cool access tiers will be restored point-in-time restore.

> If you try to restore number of blobs  which are in deleted container, the point-in-time restore operation will fail.

> ***PrivateLink allows copy of  storage accounts having private links to the same virtual network as destination account.***
> ***But Point-in-time restore when having  AllowedCopyScope which copies to same Azure AD tenant or virtual network is not supported type of account.***

from [limitations-and-known-issues | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/point-in-time-restore-overview#limitations-and-known-issues)

After considering this ,
Check and have ***storage blob data contributer role*** in order to do opertaions on container .

Then the deployment will be successful.

[image]

**Reference :** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/blobservices?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template